# How to sort a python list?

Tags: python, list, sorting, nested

I have a python nested list of following format. I need to sort the list based on the third entry.

```
 interactions = [[0 for x in xrange(3)] for x in xrange(3) ]
 interactions[0] = 'TP53', 'BRCA2', 0.5
 interactions[1] = 'AGT' , 'PCALM', 0.8
 interactions[2] = 'BRCA1', 'BRCA2',0.2
```

I want to sort the list based on the third entry, means the floating point value. Please suggest one efficient method.

Comment: One suggestion. Create the list like this `interactions = []` and then  use `interactions.append` to add elements to the list. Now, you are creating a 2D list and replacing all the inner lists with tuples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`list.sort`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#mutable-sequence-types) or [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) accept optional `key` function. The return value of the key function is used as comparison key.

```
>>> interactions = [[0 for x in xrange(3)] for x in xrange(3) ]
>>> interactions[0] = 'TP53', 'BRCA2', 0.5
>>> interactions[1] = 'AGT' , 'PCALM', 0.8
>>> interactions[2] = 'BRCA1', 'BRCA2',0.2
>>> interactions.sort(key=lambda i: i[2])
>>> interactions
[('BRCA1', 'BRCA2', 0.2), ('TP53', 'BRCA2', 0.5), ('AGT', 'PCALM', 0.8)]
```

You can also use [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) in place of [`lambda`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions):

```
import operator
interactions.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(2))
```

Answer (score 1):

[`sort`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable) has a `key` argument, where you can pass in any function. In this case, make a short inline function (called a [lambda](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions)) that returns the third element from your tuple:

```
interactions.sort(key=lambda x:x[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   >> print sorted(interactions, key=lambda x: x[2])
   >> [('BRCA1', 'BRCA2', 0.2), ('TP53', 'BRCA2', 0.5), ('AGT', 'PCALM', 0.8)]
```